# Powershell select-string but with an exclusion

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\users\admin\Desktop\docs\" -recurse | 
    Select-String "smtp" | 
    group path | 
    select name
```

Which looks in all the files in that folder with the word SMTP which is great, but I want to look for files in that folder that have SMTP but don't have the word PDF in for example.

Can't figure out how to get it to do that.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance,

Comment: Are you looking for files that contain 'SMTP', but not 'PDF' on the same line, or files that contain 'SMTP', but don't contain 'PDF' anywhere in the same file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "late filter" the results from `Select-String` by applying the filter to the `.line` property of the `matchinfo` objects returned:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\users\admin\Desktop\docs\" -recurse | 
    Select-String "smtp" | 
    Where { $_.line -notlike '*PDF*' } |
    group path | 
    select name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `-like` and `-notlike`:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\users\admin\Desktop\docs" -recurse | where $_.FullName -like "*smtp*" -and $_.FullName -notlike "*pdf*"
```

Comment: You could combine both clauses as  `$_.FullName -like "*smtp*" -and $_.FullName -notlike "*pdf*"`